# Why Lua adjusts the results in this way?

Tags: lua

I'm reading the Lua Reference Manual and it says:

> Both function calls and vararg expressions can result in multiple values. [...] If an expression is used as the last (or the only) element of a list of expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless the call is enclosed in parentheses). In all other contexts, Lua adjusts the result list to one element, discarding all values except the first one.

What are the advantages of this choice?

Is it common to other programming languages?

Comment: Adjustment to single value is a nice feature.  But Lua lacks the opposite feature - preserving all the values.  For example, let square brackets mean preserving all the values, and let function f() returns `1, 2, 3`, then `return f(), (f()), [f()], f()` should return 8 values: `1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other languages that allow vararg functions and multiple return values usually require you to be more explicit. They don't have a silent shortcut for getting the first item, as Lua does. Here are some possible reasons for doing it the Lua way:

- Probably the most important reason is that it's possible to get the number of explicit items from multiple values, even if they end in `nil`. See [`select`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-select) and [`table.pack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.pack). Implicit conversion to a table would lose this information.
- You can add a second value to a `return` statement without breaking backward compatibility. Otherwise, the calling code would have to change in order to access the first return value.
- Sometimes, the second return value is an error message. Lua lets us ignore the error by pretending the function has just one return value. (Although this is probably a downside, not an advantage.)
- There may be other advantages to the syntactic sugar that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, if you support multiple return values, you probably want something like the following work:

```
local x, y, z = a()
```

On the other hand, without the the current rule, the following code

```
local x, y, z = b(), c()
```

is very hard to analyze: `x`, `y`, and `z` could hold the return values of `b()` if it returns at least 3 values (`c()`'s return values are dropped completely in this case), or they could only hold the return values of `c()` (padded filled with `nil`s) if `b()` does not return any values at all, or various combinations thereof. Note that the number of return values of functions can vary depending on circumstances.

*With* the current rule `x` always gets the first return value (which is often the most important) of `b()` (or possibly `nil` if `b()` doesn't return any), `y` always gets the first return value of `c()` (or `nil`), and and `c` gets the second return value of `c()` or `nil`. Nice and easy, and the first use case above is covered as well.

So the reason is that it's easier to decipher just by looking at the assignment which variable gets which return value. It's the same for function calls, btw.:

```
function f( x, y, z )
  -- ...
end

f( b(), c() )
```

Comment: If number of results returned by `b()` is hard to predict (as you said you have to decipher it) then why somebody would use the assignment `local x, y, z = b(), c()` ?  Most real-life use cases don't have this "deciphering problem".  For example, some functions return 3 values (3D-point), some functions return 2 values (left and right boundaries of some interval), and so on.  You also have special operator `(b())` to extract only the first value, you can write `local x, y, z = (b()), c()` if you need. There is no need to always extract the first value. This decreases language expressibility.

Comment: This adjustment feature really doesn't make sense if all you have is functions that always return the same number of values and where all those values are equally important. But that's not true for all functions in Lua. E.g. many people forget that `string.gsub` returns two values, because you rarely need/use the second one.

Comment: Some poorly-designed functions in the standard library should not be a reason to disimprove the language.  BTW, the second result from `string.gsub` is a PITA for beginners: `table.insert(t, str:gsub(...))`, I'd like it to be two separate functions instead (`gsub` and `gsubcnt`).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Its not hard, but impossible to analyse - Lua allows a dynamic number of multiple return values, while a function is also an expression syntactically. Not only that, it allows you to change the content of that expression during the lifetime of the containing chunk and that could be even eval'd from external files. So even analysis just cant give you the right number of return values consistently.

Comment: @dualed - I didn't understand you.  Lua doesn't need to predict number of values at compile time.  Instead, in runtime Lua can receive (and store at the stack) ALL the values returned from a function (not just the first of them).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff sorry, mixed up you and the AP. You're right, for Lua the problem is not static analysis. The problem is language semantics, syntax, consistency and readability, though I thought it was already discussed well enough. There are expressions that would be unpredictable for the programmer;  `x, y = f(), g()`, `f() * g()`, `f(g(), K)`, `f(g(), ...)`, ... etc. while they all become (partly) predictable once you adjust to 1.

Comment: @dualed - I'd say "be more powerful for the programmer" instead of "be unpredictable for the programmer" ;-)